# Transform data type EWKT and GeoJSON to SRID 900913

Tags: postgis, geojson, srid

Is posible transform data type EWKT with SRID 0 for example:

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((295098.566494 6006717.0377012,344018.26458971 6009163.022606,329342.355161 5972473.2490342,295098.566494 6006717.0377012)))
```

to same data type but with SRID 900913??

Also transform data type GeoJSON with SRID 0 for example:

```
{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-125016.81962652,4577493.619373099],[-124816.19981552364,4577552.93014355],[-124765.99472517562,4577419.175847012],[-124842.47121534991,4577392.905406596],[-125016.81962652,4577493.619373099]]]]}
```

to same data type but with SRID 900913

Comment: It is WKT and not EWKT....

Comment: @WKT, that must be nice to be able to write. It is WKT not EWKT :D.

Comment: @John Yes... I must confess   :P

Comment: As @WKT has said, this is not EWKT, but WKT, but anyway, all you need is [ST_SetSRID](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_SetSRID.html), as in the question you asked yesterday. ST_SetSRID sets the SRID, it has nothing to do with whether the geometry is coming from GeoJSON, WKB, WKT, EWKT or anything else -- these are just different ways of encoding the geometry and carry no information about the SRID directly.

Comment: It is better to avoid EPSG:900913 and use EPSG:3857 instead.

Comment: @WKT, every valid WKB/WKT is a valid EWKB/EWKT. http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#EWKB_EWKT

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(
ST_SetSRID(
St_GeometryFromText('
MULTIPOLYGON(((295098.566494 6006717.0377012,344018.26458971 6009163.022606,329342.355161 5972473.2490342,295098.566494 6006717.0377012)))
')
,900913)
)

SELECT ST_AsText(
ST_SetSRID(
St_GeometryFromText('
MULTIPOLYGON(((295098.566494 6006717.0377012,344018.26458971 6009163.022606,329342.355161 5972473.2490342,295098.566494 6006717.0377012)))
')
,900913)
)
```

Comment: This convert in geometry i not want change the type to geometry, only the SRID, is possible?

Comment: Just see now you asked something similar yesterday and get a complete explanation. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193835/transform-to-srid-900913

Comment: Yesterday YES wanted change to geometry data, today NO

Comment: WKT format does not have SRID. EWKT have... I just updated the answer.